# Is it possible to create a chatbot application for LinkedIn on top of their REST API's?

Tags: botframework, linkedin-api, chatbot

I would like to integrate chatbot applications on the profile of some users, allowing other users to interact with the bot, and taking control of the conversation via dialogs and NLP. I intent to use the Microsoft Bot Framework and LUIS, but first I need to know if it is possible.

[I took a look at the docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs) but found nothing about API's regarding the chat feature. However I wasn't able to take a look at the Partner Program API's (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1) does anyone who has access to them know if they provide access to the chat features? Like allowing a third party application to interact with users on behalf of another user?

Comment: "I would like to integrate chatbot applications on the profile of some users": you mean having a chatbot displayed directly on LinkedIn profile page??

Comment: @NicolasR Kind of, let's say I'm a recruiter, in this case I could want to integrate a chatbot on my profile to respond to messages from candidates, directing them regarding open jobs, or how to apply, getting CV attachments and sending them to a specific email addresses, things like that.

Comment: But... how do you think you can integrate something inside LinkedIn pages? You don't have access to their source code. (or there may be a customization possibility? I'm not aware of that but I never had a look to LinkedIn dev possibilities)

Comment: @NicolasR I was wondering if maybe through the Partner Program API's (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1) that would be possible. However I don't have access to them. If someone says it can be done through them I'll maybe try to apply to the partnership program. If not I'll skip the trouble. A customer want's to know if it is possible, I wasn't able to be 100% sure just looking the at the public API's, so maybe someone more experienced could be of some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [LinkedIn Terms of Service](https://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement), under 8.2 Don'ts, section m:

> Use bots or other automated methods to access the Services, add or download contacts, send or redirect messages;

I don't know if it's even possible or not (and looking at my personal profile, likely not), but even if so, this could be interpreted to be a violation.  Based on the wording, that violation may exist even if you're not accessing the actual LinkedIn messaging system and using another solution.  As I am not a lawyer, I may or may not be off-base on this interpretation.

Comment: Thank you. If it is not allowed in the terms of service surely they won't have it via API.

Answer (score 0):

a bot is a third party application,   You can not create third party apps that can be installed as a plugin for linkedIn,  no matter what api you use.   Not that long since they allowed video.  if they ever did something like bots, it would be created by LinkedIn,  you would pay to use the facility.